# How far apart are any two points on the Sword Coast?

Tags: forgotten-realms

I'm trying to accurately calibrate an online map I've generated in Roll20

Are there any two points on the Sword Coast (Forgotten Realms, Fearun) where the distances are known?

Comment: Accurate to what? Official setting maps? Maps from modules? Maps from the *Baldur's Gate* computer game? And any two points?

Comment: @fez - It's fairly clear what OP is asking but it would be nice to know what setting he wants to use as his baseplate.

Comment: The Sword Coast’s Board of Tourism approved its 2022 message to be: “Welcome to the Sword Coast where any two points on our map are just a dream away!”

Comment: @fez - Welp, I guess they were happy with the licenced RPG lorebook

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better question for RPG.SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This map](https://media.wizards.com/2015/images/dnd/resources/Sword-Coast-Map_HighRes.jpg) features in the licenced [Sword Coast Adventurer’s Guide](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/sc-adventurers-guide).

[image]

It includes a scale (bottom left)